# Declare either .Text, .Value, .Value2 using array to fetch data from excel

Tags: vb.net

I use Excel automation with Excel interop. My code takes excel sheet using array fetch. As you can see below i take all of them as .Value2, however i would like to specify for example that one of my excel column to be taken as .Text. How to achieve that?

```
'Convert from interop object to native vb.net object, indexed 1 to length
Dim data As Object(,) = DirectCast(_xlWorkSheet.UsedRange.Value2, Object(,))

For row As Integer = 2 To data.GetUpperBound(0) - 1
    Dim newDataRow As DataRow = dt.NewRow()

    Dim dattime As DateTime = DateTime.FromOADate(data(row, 11))
Next
```

Comment: You can find out information about Excel formatting here http://vb.net-informations.com/excel-2007/vb.net_excel_page_format.htm

Comment: @David i have one column in excel that has format: [h]:mm:ss means hours could exceed clock hour so means there could be e.g 783:34:12. When i tried to use formatting for instance: NumberFormat ="@" or whatever else i always got wrong result. Afterwords i realased the only way to get correct value from that cell when hour really exceed is to get .Text of a cell for that column. Therefore i ask to use .Text for one of columns instead of .Value2. Hope you get my point.

Answer (score 0):

> i have one column in excel that has format: [h]:mm:ss means hours could exceed clock hour so means there could be e.g 783:34:12. When i tried to use formatting for instance: NumberFormat ="@" or whatever else i always got wrong result.

Based on that description, I will assume that the value is entered into Excel as a numeric Double. i.e.: 783:34:13 equals 32.64875.

In VB.Net, you could generate a TimeSpan structure to yield the resulting day, hour, minutes and seconds components.  In the following, `rng` is an `Excel.Range` representing a single cell.

```
Dim val As Double = CDbl(rng.Value2)
Dim ts As TimeSpan = DateTime.FromOADate(val) - DateTime.FromOADate(0)
```

Now if you wanted to format this TimeSpan as a string similar to that displayed in Excel, you could do something like this:

```
Dim s As String = String.Format("{0}:{1:00}:{2:00}", (ts.Days * 24) + ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds)
```

The reason I am recommending this technique over getting the `Text` property of an `Excel.Range` is that the `Text` property will return exactly what you would see in Excel including the ever helpful "###" when the column is not wide enough to display the formatted value.

---

Edit To Address Comments:

> can you explain why you do this: - DateTime.FromOADate(0) ?

Excel encodes a date-time value as a decimal number of 24 hour periods (days) from a specified date-time that has the value of zero.  Your data is apparently making use of this fact to allow you to have a cell with a value of 783:34:12 (783 hours, 34 minutes, 12 seconds) or 32.64875 as a decimal value.

In order to retrieve the offset in (days, hours, minutes, seconds) the original value represents, you need to subtract date-time represented by its basis value (zero).

> i saw mismatch e.g: in excel : 0:04:07 (real value behind is: 12:04:07 AM) after your function i get this: 0:04:06 (so 1 sec diffrence why is that?

I can not reproduce this issue.  It is likely a rounding issue due too the limitations of floating point value representation.

---

Also, be advised that Excel supports two different date basis systems; the 1900 Date System (the default) and the 1904 Date System.  The `DateTime.FromOADate` function does its conversion based on the 1900 Date System.  The difference between these two systems is the date that is treated as zero.  You should check the `WorkBook.Date1904` property to see if you need to add addition days (1462 days) to the value retrieved from Excel when converting to a .Net DateTime.

This could effect the result of this code:

```
Dim dattime As DateTime = DateTime.FromOADate(data(row, 11))
```

See: [Differences between the 1900 and the 1904 date system in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/214330/differences-between-the-1900-and-the-1904-date-system-in-excel) for more information.

Comment: that's great i tested it but for one value i saw mismatch e.g: in excel : 0:04:07  (real value behind is: 12:04:07 AM) after your function i get this: 0:04:06  (so 1 sec diffrence why is that? For all other 15 examples was ok.

Comment: and can you explain why you do this: - DateTime.FromOADate(0) ?

Comment: @dev, I added info to addressed you comments.

Comment: as i can see default is 1900. Still about this 1 sec diffrence. Maybe could i preapre excel for you to see the values and see the diffrence?